# Best workaround to avoid lookup columns when having multiple rows per item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, column

In SP2013, I need to store CV information in a sharepoint list (CV). The problem is that a person can have more that one degree. Also, for every degree, I need to store the type, year, description and university.

I could have a lookup list (DEGREES), storing there the information, (for each CV the degrees) but every row would be used (i.e. lookup-ed) in CV only once. On the other hand, in order to show the full CV I need to have connected web parts. Also, nobody is going to ask me questions like "give me those that graduate from University of Alaska"

My workaround is : in list CV a multiple line field, each line for one degree and the degree fields separated with comma. I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with lookup list solution.

Comment: The lookup list would have 5 columns. In CV/allitems.aspx, the user won't see all 5 columns, just the first column. So, it won't have all the information in one page. Even if the lookup list, you have a calculated column=Column1_..+column5, the CV/allitems.aspx will be garbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If InfoPath were an option for you, I'd say that was your best bet.

Seeing as InfoPath is now a dead product, the alternative would be something like [Lester Sconyers](http://www.lestersconyers.com/custom-field-rendering-with-jslink/) did by implementing a Multiline Text field that uses JSLink to give a more friendly interface for recording the information.

[image: Edit Form]
[image: Display form]

Comment: The input would be done from the internet, so I need more functionality that infopath. The code could save the form as an infopath form, but that's a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CV more than just degrees?  Because if it's only the degrees, you could add a column for the person's name.  Then create a view that groups by the name column, and you'll have all the degrees for that person neatly under their name.

Comment: Actually, there are more, 4 columns that have the same characteristics. Languages, Job history, skills, etc